# Symmetric, real, invertible matrix: How to prove component multiplication equals Kronecker?

Tags: matrices, inverse, symmetric-matrices

Im currently looking for a prove. Given a real and invertible matrix $M$ with $M=M^T$, I would like to prove $M_{ij} M_{jk}^{-1}=\delta_{ik}$, where $\delta_{ik}$ is the Kronecker-delta (defined by $\delta_{i=k}=1$ and $\delta_{i\neq k}=0$).

Comment: This is not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is obviously false: any random real symmetric matrix will provide a counterexample.  For example, take $M=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1  \cr 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, so 
$M^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}\phantom{-}1 & -1  \cr -1 & \phantom{-}2\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: You are totally right, the source I got this from did have some additional constraints I did not mention, but even with them, it is never satisfied. It seems the author made a mistake there. Thanks for the help